# Is it possible to exclude a particular disk or drive from NewRelic?

Tags: newrelic

We use a crappy tool from BMC who's job is to clog all the space on its log mount, and choke.

So our infrastructure team gives this horrible little agent its own mount on our RHEL servers so it won't steal more space then we allot it.

THe problem is that in NewRelic all our servers appear yellow or red from this single mount.

How can I tell NR either from the UI or server config to ignore that mount/drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic doesn't ignore drives with the application monitor (Agent) or the Server Monitor.  I would file a feature request with the New Relic Support Team.

Response from NewRelic:

> Thanks for sending this in.
>
> As you may have already seen, Server alert policies can be configured
>   to alert when a server's fullest disk reaches a certain percentage.
>   This ca be done on the 'Server policies' page (Under 'Tools', 'Alert
>   policies' on the left side of the New Relic dashboard). However,
>   considering this disk will likely always be riding maximum capacity, I
>   understand you may need something more specific to your situation.
>
> So, that being said, I will go ahead and submit a new feature request
>   on your behalf to our product ideas team. While we can not guarantee
>   when or if this feature will be implemented, we take requests like
>   this very seriously and use them to prioritize what we implement next.
>   You will be put on a list of people to be notified if it's
>   implemented.
>
> Please let us know if you have any other questions.
>
> All the best, Jason, New Relic Support

Comment: Thought so, thanks I have submitted a request with NR